# Importance of .Include in the query

Tags: list, query, spcontext

Following [this msdn page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee534956%28v=office.14%29.aspx) on SharePoint development I have encountered the following issue that I do not understand.

**Case scenario:**
We are trying to retrieve `List` of all visible Lists that are present on a SharePoint site, together with their Title & ID.

Here is what Microsoft suggests:

```
    public static void RetrieveAllListOnWebpage()
    {
        using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext(Globals.Globals.SiteUrl))
        {
            var myList = context.Web.Lists;

            context.Load(myList,
                items => items.Where(item => item.Hidden == false)
                              .Include(item => item.Title, item=>item.Id));

            //context.Load(collListItem);
            context.ExecuteQuery();


            foreach (var item in myList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"ID: {item.Id}, Title: {item.Title}");
            }
        }
    }
```

When one tries to manipulate final `Console.WriteLine` statement to include more properties such as `Created`, it suddenly fails as we did not request this particular property in the `...Include(...item=>item.Created)`.

However when we change our initial `context.Load()` method to the following:

```
context.Load(myList,items => items.Where(item => item.Hidden == false));
```

it suddenly works without a problem no matter what properties we request.

*The question now is - why does Microsoft suggest to use `.Include()` in our `Context.Load()` method?*

One reason that came to my minds was that we are trying to minimize our footprint in the Sharepoint. This means that we in case we have a large number of Lists on our page (e.g. 100+) and we are only interested on two properties (Title & Created), and by limiting our search result we can get the response much faster which will not overload SharePoint too much with our request... Is this assumption correct?

Comment: Mainly, `Include` is used for performance, By default it loads all properties. When you use `.Include(item => item.Title, item=>item.Id));`, it sends the request for `Title` and `Id`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you already know how **CSOM** works in SharePoint though I am adding a little explanation. **CSOM** sends XML request to `Client.svc` and get **JSON** response.

[image]

So when you write something like following, then it requests for all properties in XML request.

```
context.Load(myList, items => items.Where(item => item.Hidden == false)
```

Now consider following code

```
context.Load(myList,
                items => items.Where(item => item.Hidden == false)
                              .Include(item => item.Title, item=>item.Id));
```

It does not include all properties in the XML request. It only requests for `Title` and `Id` in the XML request.

So we can say that `Include` limits XML request for better performance. Anyway what you said in your last block is correct.

> One reason that came to my minds was that we are trying to minimize
>   our footprint in the Sharepoint. This means that we in case we have a
>   large number of Lists on our page (e.g. 100+) and we are only
>   interested on two properties (Title & Created), and by limiting our
>   search result we can get the response much faster which will not
>   overload SharePoint too much with our request... Is this assumption
>   correct?